# Customizing GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I'm using Netbeans IDE to develop a UI but I'm having major trouble customizing the layouts.

What I need to do is spread a parent panel to affect 2 rows of the GridLayout:

[image]

I also tried with the GridBag Layout but it has a lot of unused space and I don't like it:

[image]

Is there a nice way to go around this problem? Thank you a lot!

Comment: I recommend using the `MigLayout` (http://www.miglayout.com/) . It is very straightforward, the code you'll write is much more readable and you can do very intermediate GUI's with this LayoutManager.

Comment: thank you for the additional layout, but I need to do it with what is provided by Netbeans only, it's kind of a restriction that I have

Comment: then use the gridbaylayout. And create your 3 Panels with the specific gui elements in there. Then try setting gridheight and weighty accordingly for panel 1 and 3. Also your GridBagConstraints should set the .fill property to .BOTH, so your elements get resized horizontal and vertical.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.